# REST API conflicting with Hadoop

Tags: java, rest, hadoop

This is the error I am getting.

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: A root resource, class
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.web.resources.DatanodeWebHdfsMethods, 
has a non-unique URI template /
```

I am using Hadoop and REST API.

This is how I am initialising REST API in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RESTMOB/CALL/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have tried removing the Hadoop JARs and it works, but I need those Hadoop JARs so what's the alternative. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

what is likely happening is some .class file(s) in the jar you removed are also present in the other jars - this is common in java and can create issue restarting your app and it might load different versions on restarts. I would open up the jars and search for duplicate class files and remove them from one jar and test. You can extract the jars to file system and search for all .class files and sort by name. Its always a good idea to eliminate duplicate .class files when possible even though it requires some tedious work

Comment: Thanks but the problem is there are lots of classes which are similar in hadoop and jerseyyy which i use for REST cant i use something like init param in my web.xml to avaoid this conflict issue

Comment: you wont be able to get around it with web.xml, a possibility would be to split the database module from the web module so they will be in different classpaths. If you don't want to split them you can also use the basic servlet method instead of jersey to host rest service and apache http client to call rest services. Hadoop has no issues with apache http client and servlet api when working together